# EF 4.1 CF + Azure: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: azure, ef-code-first, credentials, azure-sql-database

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application which uses EF 4.1 Codefirst.
Running my application the first time creates a new database, tables etc.
Everything has been working fine so far.

But after adding my application as a WebRole to an Azure Project I got an error message when I first hit the database (CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master').

Obviously it makes a difference if I start my application inside the VS Development Webserver or inside the Azure Emulator.

Here is some additional information which I believe could be relevant:

- The database does NOT exist when I run the application
- Visual Studio 2010 run as Administrator
- Trust level of my web role: Full trust
- SQL Server service (MS SQL 2008 R2 Express) is up and running

The connection string in my web.config looks like this:

```
<add name="dbContext" connectionString="server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;database=myDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I also tried using a real user instead of "integrated security". And that user had all possible database roles assigned, including sysadmin, serveradmin etc.

How I can I grant the necessary permissions to my application in order to allow creating a database while running inside the Azure emulator?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure emulator runs with the credentials of "Network Service" account. You need to add credentials for "Network Service" account on master database.

Comment: Super, perfect! I added NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE as a new login to my SQL Server, and then assigned the master database to this new login. And now it works. The database is being created. Thanks so much, Prafulla. It drove me nuts ;-)